# ¿Cómo hacer comparación de fechas de días iguales? Me da error

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer una comparación de días iguales, con un if, pero C# solo sabe compararme con un día mayor o menor, mas no sabe hacerlo con días que son exactamente el mismo. Tengo dos comparaciones de fecha como se podrá apreciar: con la segunda técnicamente no tengo el mas mínimo problema, pero a la hora de hacer la primera, donde yo doy permiso de que los días sean mayor o igual que, es donde me están surgiendo los problemas.

```
if (dateTimePicker6.Value >= dateTimePicker5.Value)
{
    if (dateTimePicker6.Value < dateTimePicker8.Value)
    {
        DiasR = DiasD - DiasS;
        if (DiasD == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No hay dia que se pueda solicitar.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (DiasD < DiasS)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No tiene los suficientes dias para solcitiar estas vacaciones, usted tiene: " + DiasD + ", y usted esta solicitando: " + DiasS);
                textBox43.BackColor = Color.Red;
                textBox43.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                callabc(2, DiasS, fechadi, fechadf, fregreso, DiasR, "Vacaciones");
                int setid = Convert.ToInt32(textBox38.Text);
                cargaCampos(setid);
                erase();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No ha seleccionado la fecha de regreso del empleado");
        
    }
}
else
{

//C# solo sabe mandarme a esta instancia, que no esta mal cuando hace comparaciones de día mayor que, pero si cuando trata de comparar días iguales. 
    MessageBox.Show("No ha colocado la fecha final, o la esta poniendo de antes de tiempo.");
   
}
```

Comment: y te fijaste si las fechas eran iguales??? o tienen hora y segundos y eso las hace diferentes??????

Comment: y por fijarte, me refiero a mirarlas en debug...

Comment: Hm, fíjate que no he hecho eso, solo mande a llamar las fechas de los dateTimePicker, mandándolos a los MessageBox, y ahí me entrego exactamente las mismas fechas.

Comment: en el message box no estas mostrando lo que tenes en los picker, estas mostrando otra cosa.. y por algo se llama dateTIMEpicker...

Comment: DEBUG.. metetelo en la cabeza.. no con un message box.. anda a ver el valor real que tienen....

Comment: Ya lo hice, y sigue pasando lo mismo, pero creo que ya se mas o menos hacer, en este caso lo mas conveniente es convertirlo a fecha a ver que pasa. Pero si, no hay realmente ningún cambio, en cuanto horas, minutos, inclusive segundo.

Comment: mostra lo que ves... a ver si es realmente asi..

Comment: Hola, soy la fecha uno: System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 01/07/2023 09:45:46 a. m.

Hola, soy la fecha dos: System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 01/07/2023 09:45:46 a. m.

Comment: donde estas mostrandos eso????

Comment: no me digas que en un textbox o un messagebox...

Comment: Mostrar salida de depurar

Comment: y eso, otra vez, transforma el resultado en tu .tostring!!!! miralo en debug!!! te aseguro, que seguro tienen algo distinto.. ms o algo, es distinto.. igual podes arreglarlo comparando solo la parte de fecha... pero miralo en DEBUG, en debug.. segui tu codigo, paralo en ese punto, y fijate que tiene cada objeto... y si no sabes hacer debug, aprende ya!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el típico problema de los milisegundos

Digamos que tienes algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    var f2 = dateTimePicker2.Value;

    Console.WriteLine(f1.ToFileTime());
    Console.WriteLine(f2.ToFileTime());

            
    if (f1 == f2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IGUAL");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DIferente");
    }
}
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer el componente DateTimePicker asigna los milisegundos actuales cuando se selecciona. Lo cual sería un error de diseño, ya que lo lógico sería que los milisegundos fueran siempre cero.

Una solución sería limpiar el DateTime creando un método de extensión

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static DateTime ToMilisZero(this DateTime f)
    {
        return new DateTime(f.Year, f.Month, f.Day, f.Hour, f.Minute, f.Second, 0, f.Kind);
    }
}
```

Y luego

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToMilisZero(); //Usamos la función
    var f2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToMilisZero(); //Usamos la función

    Console.WriteLine(f1.ToFileTime());
    Console.WriteLine(f2.ToFileTime());

            
    if (f1 == f2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IGUAL");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DIferente");
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, había usado tu método, pero no me había tomado el tiempo para agradecerte, digo mejor tarde que nunca, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Los DatetimePickers.Value contienen milisegundos como dicen arriba, para comparar solo las fechas e ignorar los segundos/milisegundos/microsegundos ,etc.
utilice ToShortDateString()

```
dateTimePicker6.Value.ToShortDateString() = dateTimePicker5.Value.ToShortDateString()
```